# unable to download SoapUI eclipse plugin

Tags: rest, testing, soap, soapui

Unable to find SoapUI plugin for eclipse . I had tried with  Help->Install New S/W-> SoapUI-http://www.soapui.org/eclipse/update/site.xml and http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/soapui-eclipse-plugin.
Do anyone know any alternate link .